# Validating existence of a nested object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to iterate over an array of objects but I get the parent object from a REST API service and sometimes the nested array of objects will be missing, for example:

```
var data = [
  {
    "post": {
      "message": "this is a test",
      "comments": [
        {
          "comment_text": "this is a comment"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

If I wish to iterate over the comments, but have no guarantee that the `post` or `comment` object will be present, I currently pre-validate using:

```
if (data && data.post && data.post.comments) {
  //iteration
}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing the validation part?

Answer (score 0):

One of the benefits of [ImmutablsJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) (outside it's core feature - immutability) is the nice API it exposes.
If your data was an Immutable `Map` object you could iterate `comments` like this:

```
data.getIn(['post', 'comments'], List()).map(...)
```

notice that this code will work without any `if` statement, as you can pass an optional default result to `getIn`, in this case a empty `List`.